# Change iface when internet is slow bash script

Tags: networking, server, bash, scripts

Need help with script that will change eth1 or eth2 ( to auto set different route ). I have eth0 that is shared to lan and two different gateways (routers), one on eth1 and second on eth2. For now that is set to auto connect and routers are set to give me the same ip, they are both on same subnet but on different ip ranges, eth1 router 192.168.1.1(10-100), eth2 router 192.168.1.2(150-200),and they are setting server to be on 192.168.3, eth0 is for share. Because I have problem that internet becomes slow and routers are reseting, I need to auto change iface when that happens, maybe ping with timeout and then to determen which iface is up , and then set it down and bring other up.
Any help would be appreciated.